# SalesForce Objects: Restapi visibility

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Not quite sure if this has been asked. In Salesforce, I can see within the object explorer and within the fields and relationships, all entries however if I perform in postman a:

https://eu40.salesforce.com/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/amazonconnect__AC_ContactTraceRecord__c/describe

and copy the results within a test document and look for a particular field I cannot find it. Is there a security setting within the fields from being accessed though a rest api?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the api user does not seem to have enough rights. Add the apiuser as an AC_Administrator and give it a try.